# Set privacy while posting to Facebook with JavaScript

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As per the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) I can set the privacy of the post while sending it to the user's wall (not friend's wall).

I tried to set the privacy public PUBLIC, `{"value","public"}` but every time I got *error 100: invalid parameter error*.

Can someone tell me what I should do to make the privacy value public?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ - you want to set the value EVERYONE, not public.

Answer (score 1):

Change the privacy to `{"value":"EVERYONE"}` and it will work, provided the user's privacy settings for your app aren't set to a lower setting.

Comment: (provided the user's privacy settings for your app aren't set to a lower setting)

Comment: Hello what do u mean by ?? provided the user's privacy settings for your app aren't set to a lower setting

Comment: It means the user can override the app sharing settings using their privacy settings. E.g. they can hide all posts from your app if they choose to do so - even with the app still using `EVERYONE`.